# SQL Syntax error. Error 1136

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1136

```
insert into students (subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board)
values ('aldjk', 'sdad', 'adasd');
insert into students (subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board)
values ('qweo', 'qpweio', 'lajkdasdk');
insert into students (subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board)
values ('xmvnc', 'escg', 'lcxede');
insert into students (subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board)
values ('zklfhqwoeui', 'blfjslkfj', 'qweqrqsada');
insert into students (subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board)
values ('xncvj', 'dadadasddadaf', 'weo');
```

When i run this code, it throws the following error.

[Picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s4jb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a 4th value :

```
insert into students (subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board)
values ('aldjk', 'sdad', 'adasd','<<ForthValue>>');
```

Answer (score 0):

IN `Insert INTO` Number of columns in INSERT into is equals to number of values passing to it, You may be missing passing value for `subject_id`

```
insert into students (subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board)
values (1,'aldjk', 'sdad', 'adasd');
--------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your fourth column's value :

If "subject_id" is Primary key of your table and it'll be Auto increment then you can leave this blank or ignore this field in query. So please use below mentioned query :

```
insert into students (`subject_id`, `subject_name`, `level_of_entry`, `exam_board`)
values ('', 'aldjk', 'sdad', 'adasd');
```

OR

```
insert into students (`subject_name`, `level_of_entry`, `exam_board`)
values ('aldjk', 'sdad', 'adasd');
```

For more [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)